# Get the text of label in static method using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, static-methods

I have a static function in which i want to get the value OF LABEL1

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SetFileNameU(List<string> someValues)
{
        string journey = Convert.ToString(someValues[0]);
        Label tbx = _________("Label1", true).FirstOrDefault() as Label;

        return "ss";
}
```

Now what should I do there? Kindly tell me

Comment: Is there a reason for wanting to use a Static method? You're going to create a potential issue with multiple users changing the value and effecting everyone else.

Comment: Label1 of which page? The WebMethod is going to be called from some client-side code presumably... so by that time we're no longer in the context of a request for a page.

Comment: You do not call a WebService to get a label on page you can find it using javascript and save a lot of bandwidth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have access to `label` text because when you call a static method, it doesn't have the instace of the View. That's why you can't acess them directly neither use `Controls` Collection.

You have to use another way to return the value that you want. Maybe have the desired value stored on another static variable.

E.g:

```
public static class MyClass {
    public static string AndHisNameIs;
}

public void SomewhereInTheCode() {
    ....
    MyClass.AndHisNameIs = "JOHN CEENA";
    ....
}

[WebMethod]
public static string SetFileNameU(List<string> someValues)
{
    string journey = Convert.ToString(someValues[0]);
    return MyClass.AndHisNameIs;
}
```

Comment: Don't use static variables like that in a web context. All visitors using the same app domain (in general all visitors of your website) will share that static variable.